# Logic error in a linked list selection sort algorithm

Tags: c++

I have gotten it to consistently work with 3 nodes, but when I raise it to 10 nodes, I get a stack that is partially sorted. The linked list class that this is attatched to definitely works properly, and I have gotten bubbleSort working properly so far. first points to the first node in the list, last to the last. count is the number of nodes in the linked list. firstNode is the node I use to hold the sorted list, so anything before it should contain all of the smallest nodes already sorted. I keep it on the last node in the sorted portion so I can replace it's link when the next node is found. I have gone over this code several times on paper, and can't seem to find the error.

```
template<class Type>
void unorderedLinkedList<Type>::selectionSort()
{
    nodeType<Type> *tempNode, *traverseNode, *preNode, *firstNode;
    tempNode=first; //initializing Nodes
    traverseNode = first;
    preNode = first;
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) //loops 1 time for setting first Node
    {
        if (tempNode->info > traverseNode->link->info) // checks for smallest Node
        {
            preNode = traverseNode;
            tempNode = traverseNode->link;
        }
        traverseNode = traverseNode->link;
    }
    if (tempNode != first) //places smallest Node in position first
    {
        if (tempNode != last) //check if tempNode is last
            preNode->link = tempNode->link;
        else
        {
            preNode->link = NULL;
            last = preNode;
        }
        tempNode->link = first;
        first = tempNode;
    }

    firstNode = first;
    for (int iteration = 2; iteration < count; iteration++) //loop that should place element into the next slot each iteration
    {
        preNode = firstNode;
        tempNode = firstNode->link;
        for (int index = 0; index < count - iteration; index++) //loop that should find the smallest element
        {
            traverseNode = firstNode->link;
            if (traverseNode->link->info < tempNode->info) //checking if node is smaller
            {
                preNode = traverseNode;
                tempNode = traverseNode->link;
            }
            traverseNode = traverseNode->link; //traverse to next node
        }
        if (tempNode != last) //check if node is the last node  
            preNode->link = tempNode->link;
        else
        {
            preNode->link = NULL;
            last = preNode;
        }
        tempNode->link = firstNode->link; //node swap
        firstNode->link = tempNode;
        firstNode = firstNode->link;
    }
} //end selectionSort
```

Comment: it should be possible to code at least the highest level of the sort in a way that is independent of the sequence representation (list or array or whatever). might help.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf ... in other words: It should interact seamlessly using the stuff from the standard ´<algorithm>´ header?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: well at least in C++03 `std::list` has its own `sort` function which should be used instead of `std::sort`. because the interface of `std::sort`, taking two iterators, is not suitable for a linked list. i was thinking more of operations such as `insert`, `remove`, some positioning stuff, that way: mostly just a matter of nameing the operations and abstracting them as functions.

Comment: This is not because it is suitable. I have to sort a linked list using 5 different types of sorts. I am still a student learning c++ and this is my assignment. The logic error is all I need help with. syntax is all working just fine.

Comment: Magical question is, what have you tried to debug it? Run code along the paper. I don't see a problem with "`printf`" debugging if you don't have anything better. If you ran it on paper only, then you don't understand the code, or you did the check badly. I don't think compiler generates troll code. I can bet it does work as it is written.

Comment: I wrote the code from scratch... so I definitely understand it. I just can't figure out what's wrong with it and had hoped someone might have worked with linked lists a lot and had some idea of a common logic error here was. I normally just use cout << and my head and paper to debug and problem, and with a linked list, I'm not sure if there is a better option. I wrote a bubble sort function the same way and got it working great with 10,000 nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
traverseNode = firstNode->link;
```

needs to be outside of your inner for loop (the one on `index`). Otherwise you are always just comparing against the same node.

Edit: You are also missing a test for when you don't have to swap nodes. Your second inner loop and subsequent link manipulation should look like your first loop (in fact, you may be able to simplify and use the same code for both)